# Dropdown window does not open on custom filtered GXT combobox

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I want to filter GXT ComboBox Store. for example if I type 'st' in combobox I want combobox to show only values that contain 'st'

[image]

Here is my implementation

```
combo = new ComboBox<MerchantDTO>(store, label);
    StoreFilter<MerchantDTO> filter = new StoreFilter<MerchantDTO>() {
        @Override
        public boolean select(Store<MerchantDTO> store, MerchantDTO parent, MerchantDTO item) {
        boolean canView = (item.getName() != null &&    item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(combo.getText().toLowerCase()));
        return canView;
    }
};
store.setEnableFilters(true);
store.addFilter(filter);
```

This filter works and shows correct values, But combobox's dropdown list does not open automatically. I have to click on combobox manually to open dropdown list and see filtered results. I am using GXT 3.1.0  and GWT 2.7.0

I tried using `combo.expand();` function but it didnt open dropdown list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. Here is sample how to add custom filter to GXT (version 3.1.0) ComboBox

**1)** Create class which extends ListStore and add String variable for user input text

```
public abstract class XListStore<M> extends ListStore<M> {

private String userText;

public XListStore(ModelKeyProvider<? super M> keyProvider) {
    super(keyProvider);
}

@Override
protected boolean isFilteredOut(M item) {
    return filter(item);
}

public abstract boolean filter(M item);

public String getUserText() {
    return userText;
}

public void setUserText(String userText) {
    this.userText = userText;
}
}
```

**2)** Initialize custom list store and implement **filter** method

```
XListStore<SampleDTO> store = new XListStore<SampleDTO>(new ModelKeyProvider<SampleDTO>() {
        @Override
        public String getKey(SampleDTO item) {
            return item.getId();
        }
    })  {
        public boolean filter(SampleDTO item) {
            boolean result = false;
            //Write you filter logic here
            return result;
        }
    };
store.setEnableFilters(true);
```

**3)** Initialize ComboBox and add Key up handler

```
ComboBox<SampleDTO> comboBox = new ComboBox<SampleDTO>(store, label);
    comboBox.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
        store.setUserText(comboBox.getText());
    }
});
```

Done. Now ComboBox will filter store according to user input and will open dropdown window automatically